# How do I fix cells in Excel that contain formulas, but are showing as empty cells?

Tags: excel

I have tried to find this scenario somewhere but haven't been able to find any useful resources.

Essentially, I have performed some work in Excel and upon returning to the file the row sizes were so large the file could not used properly, and the cells were blank. The row sizes was an easy fix, however the blank cells are strange because they still contain text/formulae.

Has anyone seen this issue before, and know how to fix it?

Thanks!!!!

[In this image, you can see that the selected sell contains some text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jyH7.png)

[Here, if I double click to edit the cell contents, there seems to be some kind of disconnect between the location of the cell, and where Excel is allowing me to edit the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iC4Hx.png)

Comment: Can you include a screenshot or something? I don't understand what you mean when you say the cells are blank but they still contain text.

Comment: @Dan My apologies, I should have included these in the first instance. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start working with "formulatext()" Excel function: if you have a formula, this returns a full string

Answer (score 0):

I've seen issues like this in the past and have always first tried the "Text to Columns" Data Tool on the Data Menu.  I have used this when cells are unexpectedly blank, or when my dates are registering as dates or formulas are registering as formulas.  It might help.